# How to set onclick listeners to all items in linearlayout through multiple include's

Tags: android, kotlin, layout, onclick, include

We are building android alarm application and also don't know much about mobile dev. So problem is: we have **days_of_the_week.xml** linear layout with horizontal days of the week, which is *included* several times in the **days_pick.xml** layout, and this layout is *included* in **activity_add_page.xml**.
We want to have an ability to somehow choose and highlight the days user pick in that component.

Is it possible to do it without writing something like this:

```
        one_week.monday_tv.setOnClickListener{
        it.setBackgroundColor(getColor(R.color.purple_active))
    }
```

days_of_the_week.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/week_layout"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/monday_tv"
        android:padding="5dp"
        android:layout_margin="5dp"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/monday" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/tuesday_tv"
        android:padding="5dp"
        android:layout_margin="5dp"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/tuesday" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/wednesday_tv"
        android:padding="5dp"
        android:layout_margin="5dp"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/wednesday" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/thursday_tv"
        android:padding="5dp"
        android:layout_margin="5dp"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/thursday" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/friday_tv"
        android:padding="5dp"
        android:layout_margin="5dp"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/friday" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/saturday_tv"
        android:padding="5dp"
        android:layout_margin="5dp"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/saturday" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/sunday_tv"
        android:padding="5dp"
        android:layout_margin="5dp"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/sunday" />

</LinearLayout>
```

days_pick.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical">


    <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
        android:id="@+id/one_week"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        android:visibility="visible"
        >

        <include
            android:id="@+id/inc_week"
            layout="@layout/days_of_the_week"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.497"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.0" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/show_two_weeks_btn"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="@string/even_odd_dp"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/inc_week"
            app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.043" />
    </androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>


    <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
        android:id="@+id/two_weeks"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        android:visibility="gone"
        >


        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/odd_tv"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
            android:rotation="-90"
            android:text="@string/odd_dp"
            android:textSize="12sp"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@+id/odd_week"
            app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.901"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/even_tv"
            android:layout_width="30dp"
            android:layout_height="18dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="24dp"
            android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
            android:rotation="-90"
            android:text="@string/even_dp"
            android:textSize="12sp"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@+id/even_week"
            app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.984"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/odd_tv" />

        <include
            android:id="@+id/odd_week"
            layout="@layout/days_of_the_week"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.497"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.0" />

        <include
            android:id="@+id/even_week"
            layout="@layout/days_of_the_week"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.497"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/odd_week"
            app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.007" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/show_one_week_btn"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="4dp"
            android:text="@string/one_week_dp"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.498"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/even_week"
            app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.0" />


    </androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>



</LinearLayout>
```

activity_add_page.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <TimePicker
            android:id="@+id/time_picker"
            style="@style/TimePickerAddingPageTheme"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:layout_marginTop="36dp"
            android:layout_marginBottom="20dp"
            android:scaleX="1.50"
            android:scaleY="1.50"
            android:theme="@style/TimePickerAddingPageTheme"
            android:timePickerMode="spinner"/>

        <include
            android:id="@+id/week_pick"
            layout="@layout/days_pick"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.212"
            android:layout_margin="20dp"/>

        <ScrollView
            android:id="@+id/scrollView2"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="400dp">

            <LinearLayout
                android:id="@+id/linearLayout"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:orientation="vertical">

                <View
                    android:id="@+id/divider2"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="1dp"
                    android:layout_gravity="center"
                    android:layout_marginStart="28dp"
                    android:layout_marginEnd="28dp"
                    android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
                    android:background="?android:attr/listDivider" />

                <EditText
                    android:id="@+id/editTextTextPersonName"
                    android:layout_width="347dp"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_gravity="center"
                    android:autofillHints="username"
                    android:backgroundTint="?attr/colorError"
                    android:ems="10"
                    android:hint="@string/signal_name_ap"
                    android:inputType="textPersonName"
                    android:maxLength="15" />

                <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="72dp">

                    <TextView
                        style="@style/EachAddingPageTextStyle"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_marginStart="30dp"
                        android:text="@string/repeat_signal_ap"
                        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
                        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
                        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
                        app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.509" />


                    <Spinner
                        android:id="@+id/repeat_spn_ap"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_marginEnd="28dp"
                        android:background="@drawable/spinner_background"
                        android:entries="@array/timeset_array"
                        android:gravity="center_vertical"
                        android:paddingStart="0dp"
                        android:paddingEnd="20dp"
                        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
                        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
                        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

                </androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>

                <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="72dp">

                    <TextView
                        style="@style/EachAddingPageTextStyle"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_marginStart="30dp"
                        android:text="@string/signal_melody_ap"
                        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
                        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
                        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
                        app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.509" />

                    <Button
                        android:id="@+id/melody_btn_ap"
                        android:layout_width="30dp"
                        android:layout_height="28dp"
                        android:layout_marginEnd="25dp"
                        android:background="@drawable/ic_arrow_left"
                        android:onClick="onClick"
                        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
                        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
                        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

                </androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>

                <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="72dp">

                    <TextView
                        style="@style/EachAddingPageTextStyle"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_marginStart="30dp"
                        android:text="@string/vibration_ap"
                        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
                        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
                        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
                        app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.433" />

                    <androidx.appcompat.widget.SwitchCompat
                        android:id="@+id/vibration_switch"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_marginEnd="25dp"
                        android:thumb="@drawable/custom_thumb"
                        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
                        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
                        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
                        app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.511"
                        app:showText="false"
                        app:switchMinWidth="40dp"
                        app:track="@drawable/custom_track" />

                </androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>

                <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="72dp">

                    <TextView
                        style="@style/EachAddingPageTextStyle"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_marginStart="30dp"
                        android:text="@string/puzzle_on_alarm_ap"
                        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
                        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
                        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
                        app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.509" />

                    <androidx.appcompat.widget.SwitchCompat
                        android:id="@+id/puzzle_switch"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_marginEnd="25dp"
                        android:thumb="@drawable/custom_thumb"
                        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
                        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
                        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
                        app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.511"
                        app:showText="false"
                        app:switchMinWidth="40dp"
                        app:track="@drawable/custom_track" />

                </androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>



            </LinearLayout>
        </ScrollView>
    </LinearLayout>

    <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
        android:id="@+id/constraintLayout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="72dp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent">

        <TextView
            style="@style/BottomBtnAddingPageTextStyle"
            android:id="@+id/cancel_tv_ap"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity=""
            android:onClick="onClick"
            android:text="@string/cancel_ap"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@+id/space2"
            app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.506"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.509" />

        <Space
            android:id="@+id/space2"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

        <TextView
            style="@style/BottomBtnAddingPageTextStyle"
            android:id="@+id/save_tv_ap"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:onClick="onClick"
            android:text="@string/save_ap"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.503"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/space2"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.509" />

    </androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>

</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

AddPageActivity.kt:

```
package com.example.alarme

import android.content.Intent
import android.graphics.Color
import android.graphics.drawable.ColorDrawable
import android.os.Bundle
import android.util.Log
import android.view.View
import android.widget.*
import androidx.appcompat.widget.SwitchCompat
import androidx.core.view.children
import androidx.fragment.app.FragmentActivity
import androidx.lifecycle.ViewModelProvider
import com.example.alarme.db.Alarm
import com.example.alarme.db.AlarmViewModel
import kotlinx.android.synthetic.main.activity_add_page.*
import kotlinx.android.synthetic.main.days_of_the_week.*
import kotlinx.android.synthetic.main.days_of_the_week.view.*
import kotlinx.android.synthetic.main.days_pick_fragment.*
import kotlinx.android.synthetic.main.days_pick_fragment.view.*
import java.sql.Time
import java.util.Calendar

class AddPageActivity : FragmentActivity() {
    private lateinit var alarmViewModel: AlarmViewModel
    var mTimePicker: TimePicker? = null
    var now: Calendar? = null
    var alarmName: EditText? = null
    var vibration: SwitchCompat? = null
    var puzzle: SwitchCompat? = null
    var weekMode: Spinner? = null

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_add_page)
        title = ""

        mTimePicker = findViewById(R.id.time_picker)
        mTimePicker?.setIs24HourView(true)

        mTimePicker?.descendantFocusability = TimePicker.FOCUS_BLOCK_DESCENDANTS

        //TODO: after localization be made, add verification of a language -> to 24 Hour mode/to AM,PM mode

        now = Calendar.getInstance()
        alarmName = findViewById(R.id.editTextTextPersonName)
        vibration = findViewById(R.id.vibration_switch)
        puzzle = findViewById(R.id.puzzle_switch)
        weekMode = findViewById(R.id.repeat_spn_ap)
        mTimePicker?.hour = now!![Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY]
        mTimePicker?.minute = now!![Calendar.MINUTE]

        alarmViewModel = ViewModelProvider(this).get(AlarmViewModel::class.java)


        // my garbage listeners

//        val daysOneWeek = one_week.children.forEach {
//            daysListener(one_week, it.id)
//        }

        one_week.monday_tv.setOnClickListener{
            it.setBackgroundColor(getColor(R.color.purple_active))
        }

        daysListener(one_week, R.id.monday_tv)

        show_one_week_btn.setOnClickListener{
            one_week.visibility = View.VISIBLE
            two_weeks.visibility = View.GONE
        }

        show_two_weeks_btn.setOnClickListener{
            one_week.visibility = View.GONE
            two_weeks.visibility = View.VISIBLE
        }


        repeat_spn_ap.onItemSelectedListener = object : AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener {
            override fun onItemSelected(parent: AdapterView<*>, view: View?, pos: Int, id: Long) {
                if (pos == 2) {
                    week_pick.visibility = View.VISIBLE
                }
                else {
                    week_pick.visibility = View.GONE
                }
            }

            override fun onNothingSelected(parent: AdapterView<*>) {
                week_pick.visibility = View.GONE
                // Another interface callback
            }
        }
    }

    private fun daysListener(weekCount: View, day: Int){
        weekCount.setOnClickListener{
            val currentDay = it.findViewById<TextView>(day)
            currentDay.setOnClickListener{
                currentDay.setBackgroundColor(getColor(R.color.purple_active))
            }
        }
    }

    fun onClick(view: View) {
        when (view.id) {
            R.id.melody_btn_ap -> {
                startActivity(Intent(this, MelodyPickActivity::class.java))
            }
            R.id.cancel_tv_ap -> {
                finish()
            }
            R.id.save_tv_ap -> {
                addAlarmToDb()
                finish()
            }
        }
    }

    private fun addAlarmToDb() {
        alarmViewModel.addAlarm(Alarm(
                0,
                "" + alarmName?.text,
                Time(mTimePicker!!.hour, mTimePicker!!.minute, 0),
                true,
                vibration?.isChecked!!,
                0, // will be fixed later with updated UI
                weekMode?.selectedItemPosition!!
        ))
    }
}
```

So as you can see I've tried to use forEach but it didnt help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could declare a common method in `AddPageActivity.kt`. Like below:

```
 fun onClickDayOfWeek(view: View) {
    Log.d("TAG", "View Clicked having ID= " + view.id)
   view.setBackgroundColor(getColor(R.color.purple_active))
 }
```

And then handle click on each `view` like below:

```
<TextView
    android:id="@+id/monday_tv"
    android:padding="5dp"
    android:layout_margin="5dp"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="@string/monday"
    android:onClick="onClickDayOfWeek" /> <!-- handling click-->

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/tuesday_tv"
    android:padding="5dp"
    android:layout_margin="5dp"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="@string/tuesday"
    android:onClick="onClickDayOfWeek" /> <!-- handling click-->
```

Answer (score 0):

Although it's an old question this can be another solution.
From the layout where you want to hear:

```
fun example(){
    setContentView(R.layout.exampleLayout)
    val currentView: View =findViewById(R.id.exampleLayout)
    userActivityListener(currentView)
    ...
}
```

and the listener method:

```
fun userActivityListener(currentView: View) {   
    currentView.setOnClickListener {        
        your code here   
    }
}
```